# regex to match a variable and get the words inside the quotations from the matching line in python

Tags: python, regex

Lets say I have this variable

```
myvar = "81"
```

And I want to search through the lines that has strings like this and get the word inside the quotations:

```
static public Register myReg1 = new Register("D4_STAT_1", 81);
static public Register myReg2 = new Register("D5_STAT_1", 819);
```

In this case if I want to find the "D4_STAT_1", by searching for myvar in the file, I know how to read each line, but the problem for me is how to search for a variable and get exactly the word inside the quotations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''
... static public Register myReg1 = new Register("D4_STAT_1", 81);
... static public Register myReg2 = new Register("D5_STAT_1", 819);
... '''
>>> myvar = "81"
>>> re.search('static public Register \w+ = new Register\("(\w+)", %s\);' % re.escape(str(myvar)), s).group(1)
'D4_STAT_1'
```

Depending on the circumstances (the input file), you can also use a simpler:

```
>>> re.search('Register\("(\w+)", %s\);' % re.escape(str(myvar)), s).group(1)
'D4_STAT_1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import re

myvar = 81

with open("myfile") as _file:
    for line in _file:
        match = re.search(('\((?P<register_name>".+"), %s\)' % re.escape(str(myvar))),
                          line)
        if match:
            print match.group("register_name")
```